# Error when using MSBuild.exe to publish a .NET 6.0 C# project for Windows and Linux x64 with /p:NoBuild=true

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a plain .csproj C# project targeting .NET 6.0, and I'm trying to streamline the process of building and publishing it for both win-x64 and linux-x64 runtimes. To avoid building the project twice, I'm using MSBuild.exe with the /p:NoBuild=true flag. However, I'm encountering the following error:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(296,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file C:\Users\john.doe\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9\obj\x64\Release\apphost" because it was not found.`

Here are the commands I'm using:

1. First, I run a regular build command:  `dotnet build -c Release`
2. Then, I attempt to publish the project for `win-x64` using MSBuild.exe with `/p:NoBuild=true`:

```
MSBuild.exe ConsoleApp9.csproj /p:Platform=x64 /p:TargetFramework=net6.0 /p:Configuration=Release /t:publish /p:NoBuild=true /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64
```

3. Finally, I run the same `MSBuild.exe` command again for `linux-x64`, but it fails with the error mentioned above. I noticed that the apphost file is not being generated in the obj directory during the build process for the `linux-x64` target, whereas `apphost.exe` is generated for Windows. 
    How can I resolve this error and successfully publish my project for both `win-x64` and `linux-x64` runtimes using MSBuild.exe with the `/p:NoBuild=true` option while ensuring that apphost is generated for the `linux-x64` target during the build process?

```
MSBuild.exe ConsoleApp9.csproj /p:Platform=x64 /p:TargetFramework=net6.0 /p:Configuration=Release /t:publish /p:NoBuild=true /p:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64
```

I believe this should be possible, because Visual Studio can already do this (see at the bottom, it says 1 project up-to-date):

[image]

---

side note: I need to use `msbuild.exe` instead of `dotnet publish`, because I reference a C++/CLI project.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/29296

Comment: Why do you use msbuild instead of `dotnet publish`?

Comment: I have to use msbuild.exe, because my project references a C++/CLI project. However same thing happens with dotnet publish.

Comment: Could you provide a sample .csproj file in this situation?

Comment: here is a reproducible sample https://gist.github.com/mbalous/8f0b3108da60b4d4176bf7ec3fb4b108

Answer (score -2):

Take a look of these command, those works fine on my side:

```
MSBuild.exe ConsoleApp9.csproj /t:Restore /p:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64
MSBuild.exe ConsoleApp9.csproj /p:Platform=x64 /p:TargetFramework=net6.0 /p:Configuration=Release /t:publish /p:NoBuild=true /p:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64
```

[image]

If still doesn't work, please share more info about your project(a minimal reproduce sample is ok, such as a .csproj file).

Comment: Here is a reproducible sample https://gist.github.com/mbalous/8f0b3108da60b4d4176bf7ec3fb4b108

Comment: created issue in github https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/36693